# Vector element data corrupted following a find() action

Tags: c++, stdvector, corruption

I am constructing a Compiler using C++.  During Semantic Analysis I'm encountering a data corruption issue.  I have a functionList vector which stores a list of functions containing the name of the function, type, params and block of statements.

A function is tracked in the functionList vector whenever it's first encountered throughout the source code:

```
virtual void Visit(AST::FunctionDeclare& p_node) override {
    if (ST->Insert(p_node.getName(), p_node.getType())) {
        p_node.getParams()->Accept(*this);
        p_node.getBlock()->Accept(*this);

        if (p_node.getType() != typeStack.top()) {
            Error("Function return type is incorrect!");
            return;
        } else {
            typeStack.pop();
        }

        // Keep track of this declared function to run it when called.
        AST::FunctionDeclare newNode = p_node;
        functionList->push_back(&newNode);
    } else {
        hasErrored = true;
    }
}
```

The Lookup action below when verifying a function call causes the data corruption mentioned:

```
virtual void Visit(AST::FunctionCall& p_node) override {
    // Verify function exists
    if (ST->Lookup(p_node.getName()) == "") {
        std::string errorText = "No function with name '" + p_node.getName() + "' was found.";
        Error (errorText);
        return;
    }

    // Locate and setup required function
    AST::FunctionDeclare *pFunc = nullptr;
    // Find required function declaration
    for (auto tempFunc : *functionList) {
        if (tempFunc->getName() == p_node.getName()) // got it!
            pFunc = tempFunc;
    }
```

The Lookup action does the following:

```
    // Returns type if found, empty if not
    std::string Lookup (std::string p_name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _scopeVector.size(); i++) {
            if (_scopeVector[i]->find(p_name) == _scopeVector[i]->end()) {
                // No match yet
            } else {
                return _scopeVector[i]->find(p_name)->second; // return var type
            }
        }
        std::cerr << "Type name " << p_name << " not found in all of stack" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }
```

It appears as though I'm keeping track of a memory location that is being lost when I do a simple find() action.  I didn't expect this action to alter the data after it's been set, am I wrong?  What's the right approach in this case to avoid memory corruption?

Comment: `AST::FunctionDeclare newNode = p_node;   functionList->push_back(&newNode);` -- You are storing a pointer to a local variable.  Ask yourself what happens when that function returns and that local no longer exists.  Second, why are you not using `std::find_if` in the `Lookup` function instead of writing a loop?

Comment: The scopeVector is a vector of maps.  I'm running a find within the map of the vector to check if within one of the scopes I'm looping in, the variable name I'm checking exists or not.  Given that I should store a new copy in the vector "functionList" how do I create a copy into it?

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr` if your goal is to "share"  a pointer.  Second, that loop can be eliminated using `auto iter = std::find_if(scopeVector.begin(), scopeVector.end(), [&](auto& vt) { return vt->find(p_name) != vt.end(); });`

Comment: I guess the only reason I wouldn't opt for it is because it would make it less readable, and considering it's already complex enough for me to track what the pointers are doing, I'm going for readability over optimization in this particular case

Comment: To you it may not be readable, but to anyone who understands C++ and the standard library, it is very readable, since it can only mean one thing (`std::find_if` can only mean one thing), and it always works due to using algorithms that will not fail.  When you write loops by hand, you risk making a mistake, plus anyone else reading the code has to first focus on the `for` to make sure it is written with no bugs.  Yes it may sound nitpicky to you, but you would not believe how many programmers screw up writing the `for` part of the loop, thus introducing bugs.

Comment: I understand, going forward this will be something I'll work on better understanding and implementing.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to a local variable here:

```
AST::FunctionDeclare newNode = p_node;
functionList->push_back(&newNode);
```

When the function returns, `&newNode` is invalid since `newNode` is a local variable.

If your goal is to share pointers, then use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AST::FunctionDeclare>>`.

Comment: If I change std::vector<AST::FunctionDeclare *> * functionList; to std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AST::FunctionDeclare>> * functionList; I can't pass p_node directly.  What would need to change in FunctionDeclaration provided p_node is a FunctionDeclare type (and can't be changed as parameter)

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr::get()` to get access to the raw pointer (and make sure that function doesn't `delete` that pointer.

Comment: get() would need to be called on p_node in this case?  Due to the visitor design pattern I'm implementing, this is not really an option.  I don't suppose something like functionList->push_back(std::shared_ptr<AST::FunctionDeclare>::get(p_node)); is possible?

Comment: Well you can't store the address of a local variable -- that's the bottom line.  Maybe you should rethink your design, given now that you're aware of `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: A redesign at this stage is impossible given this compiler task is due in a week.  Admittedly yes, I regret setting it up the way I did, and I am guessing there aren't any other options left anymore.

Comment: What if you simply stored the address of `pNode`, i.e. `functionList->push_back(&pNode);`?  That takes the address of the argument that was passed, instead of taking the address of a local variable.

Comment: That does indeed seem to solve the issue... And I also actually understood what you meant by storing local variable address when falling out of scope.  I'm just not sure if p_node will stay in scope or not at this stage.  It doesn't seem like it will cause issues as is.